# What's the differences between the packages openni_camera and openni_launch?

Tags: kinect, openni-launch, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are 2 launch files `kinect_frames.launch` and `openni_node.launch` and 1 node `openni_node` in the openni_camera package.

And for openi_launch package, there are several launch files

```
depth.launch             device.launch            kinect_frames.launch     rgb.launch               
depth_registered.launch  ir.launch                openni.launch
```

and no nodes.

I'm wondering the differences between openni_camera/openni_node.launch and openni_launch/openni.launch.

And what are the other launch files such as `depth.launch` and `device.launch` in openni_launch package for? How do I use them?

Thanks for answering.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28542/what%27s-the-differences-between-the-packages-openni_camera-and-openni_launch?/) by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[openni_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera) contains the driver for the OpenNI devices. The functionality is broken up into nodelets, individually responsible for publishing and processing various pieces of data.

[openni_launch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch) is just a convenience package, providing launch files for the `openni_camera` nodelets.

There are two high-level launch files.

- `openni.launch` brings up all the launch files for the nodelets.
- `openni_node.launch` brings up the system in a node instead of nodelets.

The rest of the launch files are just building blocks - you can use them to bring up the system in a [distributed manner](http://answers.ros.org/question/27921/kinect-how-do-i-convert-depth-image-to-pointcloud), or if you're only interested in [partial data](http://answers.ros.org/question/10585/bag-a-kinect-for-more-than-30-seconds#15602).

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1